# From random to XPath

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I have 3 random generated numbers with random function

```
random = random.sample(range(1, 10), 3)
print (random)

Result is: [1, 6, 8]
```

and have XPath where need to change result for each number from result

```
For 1st number:
'//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div'

For 2nd number:
'//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[6]/div'

For 3rd number:
'//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[8]/div'
```

Tried with for loop but not working

```
for i in random:
    '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div['+ i[0] +']/div'
```

Comment: In future, I'd recommend specifying what the actual error you are encountering is. It makes it easier for someone to assist. E.g. in this case, you could post the error message `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` generated by Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your loop

```
for i in random
```

iterates for each element in the `random` list. If you were to print out `i` in the loop, you'll find it is an element of the list rather than a list itself. So it doesn't make sense to index it like you have done: `i[0]`.

However, if you remove the indexing and just use `i`, you will still encounter a new error - since `i` is an integer and not a string - you can't concatenate an integer with strings. So, to correct this, you should cast it like this: `str(i)` and then it should work.

So the final solution would be:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div['+ str(i) +']/div'
```

**Alternative:**

You can use Python 3's f-strings to avoid the string concatenation and type conversion:

```
xpath = f'//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[{i}]/div'
```

Comment: Than you very much! first option working. Second show me error. Maybe need ' '? But this is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. For the second version, this would require Python 3.6+ (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) -- which is the oldest supported version at the moment. So if you're using anything lower, you should upgrade.

Comment: Using 3.9 but don't know why not working. Can you help me with one more problem, it is simple. So, have one input box where have text, I want to change it but when call driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').clear() don't want to remove. If I try same from python shell it working. Tried with timeout but can't clear.

Comment: Best to ask this as a separate question, since this is getting off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Also, please see the comment I made on your question to provide a more specific explanation of errors encountered. When you say you "don't know why not working", it makes it difficult to assist.

Comment: I found why 'Alternative' not working. it is because have "f" before // sorry this is my mistake. I understand what you say to me, thank you. And I have opened new question for .clear() problem